# Java Message Service and Haskell

Tags: java, haskell, jms

I was wondering if there is any way to receive JMS messages from some provider like ActiveMQ or WebMQ in a Haskell program. I've seen that there is a Haskell client for ActiveMQ but it seems to be unmaintained.

Has anybody experience with this or any kind of advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the main libraries we currently have are:

- [amqp](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/amqp)
- [zero-mq](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zeromq-haskell)

If those aren't suitable, you might use them as a starting point to develop your own library.

Comment: Thanks, I think that should help me. I was looking for a way to communicate a Java process with a Haskell one, so I guess I can translate a message from WebMQ to rabbitMQ and send it to Haskell.

Sadly, writing my own library is far beyond my current haskell level ...

Comment: Other options could be redis or protocolbuffers.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is just java/haskell IPC you may want to look at thrift (see http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/), which I've had good success with so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can access ActiveMQ using the Stomp protocol with this library https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stomp-queue

You can enable Stomp on ActiveMQ like this:

```
<transportConnectors>
<transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localhost:61613"/> 
</transportConnectors>
```